# What is the meaning of the "*" in names of various learning/search algorithms?

Tags: search-algorithms

For example, consider L* algorithm for learning a regular language, or A* search algorithm. What do these names - in particular, the star character - mean?
It looks like it might be the case that the star is used in a way similar to the Kleene star - e.g. apparently, A* was preceded by A1 and A2.

Comment: This question has already been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470253/astar-explanation-of-name) on stack overflow.